# Request to reset the password ask current password

Tags: 7, users

My problem with Drupal is that when I choose "Request new password" and submit, it sends me a email with a link

> example.com/?q=user/reset/69/1376903015/wiUMZxM27RkYYAAr6zHZfqz6BH4sVMHDAfGoaeZT-Cc

I can login to account by clicking over that link. When I do the same it logged in me and redirects me to user edit page

> example.com/?q=user/69/edit&pass-reset-token=-yS11phdH8HuId-5wpaKrdI6KyWOtfV098jZ5mXb_C0

Now I want to reset my password but when I click on password tab `example.com/?q=user/69/password`,  it ask me my account's current password. But I (may be a user) don't know current password . So How can I change password?

One point I noticed that when I put pass-reset-token on the password change URL like this

> example.com/?q=user/69/password&pass-reset-token=-yS11phdH8HuId-5wpaKrdI6KyWOtfV098jZ5mXb_C0

I can reset my password without putting current password.

It means that token does not apply on the password tab link. Do I need some module or change in core user module to rectify this problem?

### WHAT I DID FOR TIME BEING / TEMPORARY SOLUTION

I edited file : modules/user/user.pages.inc
    //on line Number 142 updated

```
drupal_goto('user/' . $user->uid . '/edit', array('query' => array('pass-reset-token' => $token)));
```

to this

```
drupal_goto('user/' . $user->uid . '/password', array('query' => array('pass-reset-token' => $token)));
```

Changed "edit" to "password"

Now my goal is complete. I know it not a good solution.

Any suggestion or answer would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of drupal is this?

Comment: I am using Drupal 7

Comment: I found out from status report It's Drupal 7.22 version

Comment: Looks like a bug in core, but vanilla core does not have this problem, so... maybe you need to disable some module instead, if something prevents password recovery flow from working? Maybe you have some kind of redirect set up and it removes security token, or overrides login redirect preventing password change page from appearing just after link click?

Comment: When you are logged-in, a URL like example.com/user/69/password (where 69 is the user ID for your account) just shows you the user profile; when you are not logged-in, a URL like that gives you an access denied error. Definitively, what you describes is not what Drupal core does.

Comment: not that its directly related but if you have drush installed you can do drush uli to auto generate the user-login link without having to send yourself the email

Comment: Hey, are u the admin of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited file : modules/user/user.pages.inc
    //on line Number 142 updated

```
drupal_goto('user/' . $user->uid . '/edit', array('query' => array('pass-reset-token' => $token)));
```

to this

```
drupal_goto('user/' . $user->uid . '/password', array('query' => array('pass-reset-token' => $token)));
```

Changed "edit" to "password"

Now my goal is complete.

Answer (score 3):

[No Current Password](https://drupal.org/project/nocurrent_pass) module allows you to make this field optional.

Also, there's [an issue in core](https://drupal.org/node/1832468) about this.

Comment: I want user to put current password in case of normal login and edit. But when user login through forgot password link, system should not ask current password.

Comment: As stated [here](https://drupal.org/node/1314654#comment-5138056): "you need to make sure you log out, and then go to user/password and request the password reset".

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had to logout every time when use forgot password.